# How this $L^2[a,b] \subset L^1[a,b]$ will help me in the solution?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have to solve this question:

By Hölder Inequality, we have $L^2[a,b] \subset L^1[a,b].$ Show that the set $L^2[a,b],$ considered as a subset of a complete metric space $L^1[a,b],$ is of first category.

But I do not know how can I use this part  "By

Hölder's Inequality, we have $L^2[a,b] \subset L^1[a,b]$."

Is it used in choosing my following set: For $n \in \mathbb N,$ set $$B_n = \{f \in L^2[a,b]\mid \|f\|_1 \le n \}$$

How can I prove that $L^2[a,b] = \bigcup_n B_n$ ? Any help with this please?

Also, if I used this cover $$B_n = \{f \in L^2[a,b]\mid \|f\|_2 \le n \}$$
will it did the job (as it is trivially a cover)

Comment: `$` is only for maths, not a general TeX-escape. You can use HTML like `&ouml;` or your favourite native unicode producing shortcut on your OS.

Comment: If $f\in L^2,$ then $\|f\|_2<\infty.$ So  $\|f\|_2<n$ for some $n$ and thus $f\in B_n.$